# How to write to file in ANSI coding in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, csv

My file export action in my MVC app generate data in CSV in UTF8Encoding.

```
return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
```

When it is opened in Excel, the apostrophe `'` is displayed as `â€™`. But when it is opened in a text editor, the aprostrophe is correctly displayed.

Of course we don't want to force our users to import the CSV and specify the encoding from their Excel. I looked into `System.Text` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), but find no `AnsiEncoding` to use.

#### Update

Also tried

```
return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
```

The apostrophe is then turned into `?` in both excel and text editor.

What is the way to generate our CSV in an Excel compatible encoding?

Comment: Did you try `Encoding.Unicode` ?

Comment: maybe `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(...` ?

Comment: Where is `sb` coming from? What is the actual value of this string? I am curious what the actual value is that is not correctly translated by Excel. Also what culture are your users in (US based or maybe a country that uses a cyrillic alphabet)?

Comment: `sb` is a `StringBuilder`